# I am facing "SSH access" issue while accessing linux server

Tags: linux, unix, jenkins, ssh, ssh-keys

I am unable to access from A Server (10.61.8.XXX) to B Server (10.61.16.XX). 
Whenever try to access B server from A it keep on asking password even after SSH keys pasted in A server generated from B server.However i can able to access A server from B server without password. I don't want to regenerate SSH keys again because jobs existing in jenkins running based upon these old keys. Pls leet me know the status to confirm and commands to make this works.

Thanks in advance !!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you check file and directory permissions on host B?

On host B, fix them with

```
$ chmod go-w $HOME $HOME/.ssh
$ chmod 600 $HOME/.ssh/authorized_keys
$ chown `whoami` $HOME/.ssh/authorized_keys
```

(see the OpenSSL [FAQ](https://www.complang.tuwien.ac.at/doc/ssh/faq.html#3.14)).

Comment: I used above comments in B server but still asking password to access from A server to B server.

Answer (score 0):

1. Check if A server's publickey has been added to B servers's `.ssh/authorized_keys`
2. On server A `cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub`
3. On server B `cat ~/.ssh/authorized_keys`

If A's publickey isn't in B's authorized_keys, just add it to the bottom of B's authorized_keys

Comment: I did all whatever you mentioned above. But no chance :(

Comment: Any other possibilities.

Comment: could pls upload the output of the commands above